# How to prevent overflow when calculating min & max sum of the elements by excluding one element in the list

Tags: java, java-stream, biginteger

I need to find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly (size - 1) elements in the arrays

Example:
arr = [1,2,3,4,5] minSum = 1+2+3+4 = 10 , maxSum = 2+3+4+5 = 14

Initially, I wrote the following code

```
public static void miniMaxSum(List<Integer> arr) {
    List<Integer> sorted = arr.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Integer totalSum = sorted.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    Integer minSum = totalSum - sorted.get(sorted.size()-1);
    Integer maxSum = totalSum - sorted.get(0);
    System.out.println(minSum + " "+maxSum);
}
```

For the simple test cases, it is working as expected, but then for the numbers with higher value it is overflowing and resulting in negative values, so I used BigInteger.

```
public static void miniMaxSum(List<Integer> arr) {
    List<Integer> sorted = arr.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    BigInteger totalSum = BigInteger.valueOf(sorted.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
    BigInteger minSum = totalSum.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(sorted.get(sorted.size()-1)));
    BigInteger maxSum = totalSum.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(sorted.get(0)));
    System.out.println(minSum + " "+maxSum);
}
```

Even then, it is resulting in negative values

Input : 793810624 895642170 685903712 623789054 468592370

Output : -1722871536 -1295821736

Why is it resulting in negative values even after using BigInteger, and how should it be handled?

Comment: You'll need to convert your integers to `BigInteger` before summing them.

Comment: Yup.  The code is currently computing the sum using `int` / `Integer` arithmetic and **then** converting the result to a `BigInteger`.  That's too late to avoid the overflow.

Comment: (For the record ... with those input values you could do the computation using `long` / `Long` rather than `BigInteger` and still get the right answers.)

Answer (score 2):

As said by others, converting the value to `BigInteger` after the data loss happened, will not solve your problem. The operation itself has to be performed using a larger data type than `int`.

But sorting the list, just to get minimum and maximum, also is very inefficient. There is a built-in operation, `summaryStatistics()`, which performs all necessary operations at once, getting mimimum, maximum, and the sum. It uses `long` for summing, which is sufficient to process all ordinary collections which can not have more than 2³¹ elements.

```java
public static void miniMaxSum(List<Integer> arr) {
    IntSummaryStatistics s = arr.stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics();
    long totalSum = s.getSum();
    long minSum = totalSum - s.getMax();
    long maxSum = totalSum - s.getMin();
    System.out.println(minSum + " " + maxSum);
}
```

Note further that there is no reason to use boxed `Integer` or `Long` objects here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you create `totalSum`, the overflow already happened as you summed the integers as `int`, which means the result is also an `int`. Only then does your code convert this overflowed result to a `BigInteger`.

Instead you need to do the calculation using `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger totalSum = sorted.stream()
        .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, 
                (sum, value) -> sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(value)),
                BigInteger::add);
```

Which is equivalent to doing:

```
BigInteger totalSum = sorted.stream()
        .map(v -> BigInteger.valueOf(v.longValue()))
        .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Why is it resulting in negative values even after using BigInteger, and how should it be handled? ..."*

Utilize the *[map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function))* method to parse the *stream* as *BigInteger* values.
And, the *[reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator))* method to total the elements.

```java
List<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<>(arr);
Collections.sort(sorted);
BigInteger min
    = sorted.stream()
            .limit(sorted.size() - 1)
            .map(x -> new BigInteger(String.valueOf(x)))
            .reduce(BigInteger::add)
            .get();
BigInteger max
    = sorted.stream()
            .skip(1)
            .map(x -> new BigInteger(String.valueOf(x)))
            .reduce(BigInteger::add)
            .get();
System.out.println(min + " "+max);
```

Output

```
10 14
```